# Regular expression, SQL replace

Tags: regex

I have a text file containing about 1900 SQL [stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure). My boss told me that I have to replace all the temporary tables with table variables!

I will give you an example. I have to replace

```
CREATE TABLE #OneTable (contact_id numeric(10,0) null, contact char(80) null)
```

with

```
DECLARE @OneTable TABLE (contact_id numeric(10,0) null, contact char(80) null)
```

As you can see, the difficult part is to add the keyword **TABLE** after the table name.

How do I build a regular expression which can sort this problem out?

---

#### More Examples

```
CREATE TABLE #accounts (guest_id numeric(10,0) null, ... state char(30) null)
```

I use [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) to find a GUI selection. I input

```
CREATE TABLE #\(.\{-1,} *\)(
```

and I get:

```
Pattern not found \V\cCREATE TABLE #\(.\{-1,} *\)(
```

<sub>Note to well meaning editors: the lines starting with "CREATE TABLE" should be left in place. This is **text**, not SQL code, so leave the format be!</sub>

Comment: How consistent is the format? Do all of the CREATE TABLEs have exactly that format or is there some variation? What tools do you have for working with regexes?

Comment: The format is always like that.I use Notepad++ but I can use whichever text editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can try these find/replace patterns:

**Find:** `CREATE TABLE #(.+)`

The `(.+)` part means match any character at least once, and the parentheses are used to group that part.

**Replace:** `DECLARE @\1 TABLE`

The `\1` here is a back-reference to the first (and only) grouping we used in the find pattern.

Be aware that the find pattern is greedy, but should work if all your table declarations are on their own line as shown in your example. Otherwise, you can try modifying it to allow it to match any character that is not whitespace, a carriage return, or a newline.

Such a pattern would look like this: `CREATE TABLE #([^\s\r\n]+)`

In this pattern the `[ ... ]` is a character class, and placing a `^` at the very beginning of it makes it a negative character class so that matching stops when those characters are encountered. `\s` represents whitespace characters, `\r` is carriage return, and `\n` is newline.

Answer (score 1):

In **PostgreSQL** it could work like this:

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace(
  'CREATE TABLE #OneTable (contact_id numeric(10,0) null, contact_full char(80) null)'
,E'CREATE TABLE #(.+?) *\\('
,E'DECLARE @\\1 TABLE (');
```

But you are working with SQL Server, obviously.

---

In **vim** the same regular expression used in a substitute command:

```
:%s/CREATE TABLE #\(.\{-1,} *\)(/DECLARE @\1 TABLE (/gc
```

Some explanation:
`%` .. globally (replace everywhere)
`s` .. substitute
`\(.\{-1,} *\)` .. captures the match for reuse in a back reference
`.\{-1,}`  .. non-greedy variant of `.\+` - 1 or more characters (until next occurrence of a space (or `(`)
`*)\\(` .. one or more space before the `(`
`\1`  .. back reference
`/gc` .. `g` = substitute globally (repeatedly), `c` = ask confirmation every time

---

Improved command takes windows line breaks into account and adds tolerance:

```
%s/CREATE \+TABLE *#\(.\{-1,}\)[[:space:]\r\n]\{-}(/DECLARE @\1 TABLE (/gc
```

`[[:space:]\r\n]\{-}` .. zero or more of space and line breaks before the opening bracket

Comment: @KenWhite: the example **is** processing text and not stored procedures. It demonstrates a solution with POSIX-style regular expressions. PostgreSQL is just the platform - the OP did not name his platform.

Comment: Thanx but I am managing my sql file via Notepad++ (or such text editor applications).

Comment: @user597243: the regular expression I demonstrate works the same everywhere - as long as POSIX-style regular expressions are used. You need to disclose the tool you are working with in the question or we have to guess.

Comment: Got it. My mistake - misread because of the last paragraph of your answer combined with the first sentence. My apologies - at least I just commented and didn't downvote. :)

Comment: @Erwin I use Notepad++ but it does not support POSIX. Can you suggest me a POSIX editor for Windows? Thanx in advance!

Comment: @user597243: I added an example for `vim`. Can you work with that?

Comment: @Erwin I just downloaded. I got a bit lost. I selected MAKE and I pasted your command string but it only found 9 matches. I am comparing them to the other thousands I have and I do not find any difference. Is it that I may use VIM wrong? Thanx!

Comment: @user597243: can you paste a couple of the strings that are not found in your question, please?

Comment: I get this message in VIM when I use the FIND in the GUI: Pattern not found: \V\cCREATE TABLE #\(.\{-1,} *\)(

Comment: CREATE TABLE #accounts
(guest_id  numeric(10,0) null,
 guest_name  char(50) null,
 address  char(100) null,
 city   char(20) null,
 zip   char(20) null,
 state   char(30) null)

Comment: @user597243: Please edit your question with examples instead of putting it into comments. I tested your new example in vim (on Debian Linux) and it worked fine.